# How to understand first install in Android Apps?

Tags: android, installation

I need to make a greeting message when the user installed and run apps for the first time.
What's the simple way to get the app is running for the first time?

Comment: Check for a SharedPreference boolean flag. If it's not set, show greeting, then set it.

Comment: Thank you Ken. I think settings is better as you told me. It can be made  null by default and set it after first install to check every time

Answer (score 1):

Use `SharedPreferences` to store a flag of whether you need to show the message or not.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean showMsg = prefs.getBoolean("show_msg", true);
if (showMsg) {
    // show the message
    // then save the flag
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("show_msg", false);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Put this in `onCreate()` or similar.

Next time the snippet is run the value will be false so the message will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting `Toast` objects. See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).